# Cleanest way to check all sub-arrays are defined

Tags: javascript

I was just writing a little *game of life* script, seen as I'd never really done it.  I have created a matrix array that has sub arrays of columns, each containing the values of each row in that column.  When I loop through to check the neighbours I want to count them like the below:

```
var count = 0;
count += this.data[i-1][j-1];
count += this.data[i-1][i];
count += this.data[i-1][j+1];
count += this.data[i][j-1];
count += this.data[i][j+1];
count += this.data[i+1][j-1];
count += this.data[i+1][i];
count += this.data[i+1][j+1];
```

Obviously on the `i-1` and `i+1` indexes will cause a problem at the beginning and end of the arrays.  I can check for undefined on the value of the rows (the deepest value) like so:

```
count += typeof this.data[i-1][j-1] !== 'undefined' ? this.data[i-1][j-1] : 0;
```

But if the columns array is undefined obviously it will error and I can't check this without writing a few more lines.  Is there anyway I can catch this error in this one line, or is there a quicker way to get this data.  I just don't want lots of try/catches or if/elses to account for the edges of the matrices?

I know I could remove the sub-array structure and just have one long array of data but I was just curious about efficient ways of dealing with this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cleanest" is a subjective term, but three possibilities for you:

1. Use JavaScript's [curiously powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

   ```
   count += (this.data[i-1] || [])[j-1] || 0;
   ```

   That works for two reasons:

   1. In JavaScript, accessing an array index that doesn't exist returns `undefined`. It doesn't cause an error.
   2. Unlike many programming languages, JavaScript's `||` returns its first operand if that operand is truthy and its second operand if not, rather than a boolean. Truthy values are values that aren't falsey; falsey values are `0`, `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course `false`. So `1 || 0` is `1`, `undefined || 0` is `0`, and `0 || 0` is also `0`.

   Note that the `|| []` part of that won't create an array unless the `this.data[i-1]` part is `undefined`. But if you're worried about creating temporary arrays like that, you could have just one defined throughout your script (`var blank = [];`) and then use it:

   ```
   count += (this.data[i-1] || blank)[j-1] || 0;
   ```
2. Define your arrays (both the "vertical" one and all the "horizontal" ones) two elements too big and set the values around the edges to 0. Then loop from `1` to `< length - 1`, and you don't have to worry about going out of bounds because the `-1` case will take you to the 0th element, which has the value `0`, and the `+1` case will take you to the `length-1` element, which also has the value `0`. This offers quite clean code at the expense of a small bit of extra memory. Or:
3. Have a function to get the value which checks the coordinates and returns `0` if either is invalid. This offers quite clean code at the expense of a small bit of added overhead.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 seem like compromises, whereas perhaps a single array of linear data seems like it might be the best option in that case. Would that generally be the most efficient method?  I like option 1 but it doesn't seem to work if the value of the first array is undefined, because trying to get an index of an undefined error causes an error instead of a falsey value (which seems to be what the `||` looks for).

Comment: @richieahb: *"...perhaps a single array of linear data seems like it might be the best option in that case..."* Yes, but you said you wanted alternatives to that. *"...because trying to get an index of an undefined error causes an error instead of a falsey value"* Not in JavaScript it doesn't. Try it. :-) `var a = ['x']; console.log(typeof a[-1]);` will show `"undefined"`.

Comment: I did, say that although I wasn't quite sure whether I was correct in my assertion either ;) and it does seem to be erroring out? I seem to be getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined `?

Comment: @richieahb: Ah, yes. :-) Because `this[i-1][j-1]` breaks down into `var tmp = this[i-1]; tmp[j-1]` and of course, if `this[i-1]` returns `undefined`, we end up trying to access `[j-1]` on it. The error isn't the array indexing, but the fact we tried to index into `undefined`. I've updated the answer to handle that.

Comment: Wow, I like that - that's what I came here to learn.  Thanks!

Comment: @richieahb: It's a fun language. :-)